# How to Checkout Files and Not Directory Structure with Tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, pic

Currently my company uses Tortoise SVN to store many include files and main code files all in the top level of our repository. It is a mess, but it may be the only way it works with Pic Basic. It looks like:

> Software>
>
> Software>include_file.pbp
>
> Software>project1_file.pbp
>
> Software>project1_file_branch1.pbp
>
> Software>...

Ideally we would use the standard branch and tag structure and organize the root directory by project and keep our Global Includes in a seperate folder like so:

> Software>
>
> Software>Includes>
>
> Software>Includes>include_file.pbp
>
> Software>Project1
>
> Software>Project1>branches
>
> Software>Project1>branches>branch_1
>
> Software>Project1>branches>branch_1>project1_file.pbp
>
> Software>Project1>trunk
>
> Software>Project1>trunk>project1_file.pbp

The problem is that when I checkout files, it brings all the directory structure with it. When compiling my code, PicBasic(PBP) requires include files to be in a child directory or the same directory.

**Is it possible to just checkout selected files and not the directories?** This way the include and project file can be pulled from seperate folders on the repository to the same folder on my computer.

**If not, is there another way to organize the directory so that multiple projects can access the global includes?**

If not, is there a different versioning software that can do this?

Surely the problem is not just with PBP and other people have experienced trying to compile working copies of includes into projects that are in separate directories.

Comment: Are you using one repository for everything on different repositories for globals and every project

Comment: I can organize it either way. Currently everything is in one repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to just checkout selected files and not the directories?

Yes - right click in explorer, select SVN checkout.  When the dialog pops up, click on the elipsis(...) and navigate to the file you want then click OK.

> Is there another way to organize the directory so that multiple projects can access the global includes

Yes - but you will need admin (the one called administrator - not an admin user: they are different beasts) privilege.  Use mklink to link the global includes into your project directory.

You can always navigate down to the project directory and only check out from that point.  I'll have a read of the pbp manual - see if it is possible to include from a path.

**Edit** Other techniques for include paths

**Relative paths**

pbp allows relative and absolute paths.  For instance if the directory structure is like

```
+--global.inc
+--project1
   +--project1.pbp
```

You can use

```
include "..\global.inc"
```

This means that all the projects must live under the directory structure

**Virtual drives**

If that structure is not desirable, the globals can be put into a virtual drive using the subst command.  The advantage is that the projects can be located anywhere relative to the globals.  This will have to go into a batch file in your startup if it always needs to be available.  eg

```
subst P: C:\Users\CUP\Documents\Global
```

Check out all the global headers into global.  In the code

```
include "P:\global.inc"
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the first option you mentioned only allowed me to download one file from one directory. Not multiple files from different directories. I'll try the linking thing and get back to you.

Comment: Tortoise only allows either checkout from a subdirectory or individual files.  I've added more on the directory structure: may be easier than using mklink if you are in a network domain.

Comment: Aha! The relative paths is the answer!. Thank you very much. I didn't know you could use ..\ to back out of the program directory and re-enter an include directory. I was able to set it up as such:


`+--includes


   +--global.inc


+--projects


   +--project1


      +--project1.pbp`


This seems to allow for an infinite possibility of <s>complicated</s> organized directories within the repository and your working copy.

Edit: Sorry, not sure why I can't show multiple lines here.

Comment: MkLink, virtual drives will probably also work. You could also always download a working copy to a consistently named folder in C:\ and then have a shortcut on the desktop. The easiest and most robust way seems to be using relative paths with "..\inlcude.pbp" though.

Comment: For future readers, you can stack the "..\..\" over and over for projects that are buried multiple folders deep to get back to your working folder, then dive down into another include folder "..\..\includes\include.pbp"

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**

1. the include and project file **can't be** pulled from seperate folders on the repository to the same folder (directly, without some tricks):

Each Working Copy (and it's subfolders respectively) "linked" to known singe location in repo at each time. You can switch WC to another URL after checkout, but switched tree will be synced with NEW_LOCATION tree (and all objects from OLD_LOCATION not presented in NEW_LOCATION just disappear)

2. In TortoiseSVN (not in CLI SVN) you can use special format of "URL to checkout" like this

https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/customlocations-greylink/trunk/city/Abakan.bmp * https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/customlocations-greylink/trunk/city/Achinsk.bmp *...

(multiple URLs, separated by * **without spaces** /spaces added for SO-renderer/), but this is anyway partial checkout from *common base*, not unrelated nodes

**Possible solution(s)**

1. If includes are Common + Project Specific and can be stored in more than singe child folder of project code, you can

   - Collect all Commons in *some location* and add this dir to each project with externals definition (directory-type)
   - Project-specific includes will be placed in second physical folder in project-root
2. If all includes have to be in single folder, you can

   - Store Common includes and all projects in singe repo (Commons is special folder, as above) - contrary to previous case, where for dir-type externals SRC and DST can be different repos
   - Add all needed Commons as file-type externals to the folder with project-specific includes